update multiple objects in array using redux toolkit
I have a store called stories which has a userStories object stored.
Example of userStories object inside store:
       userStories:  {
          userId1: [{storyId: 1, viewedBy: [id5, id2, id9]}, {storyId: 2, viewedBy: [id1, id2, id3]}]
          userId2: [{storyId: 6, viewedBy: [id25, id42, id29]}, {storyId: 7, viewedBy: [id21, id22, id33]}]
          }

I subscribe to the stories for a particular userId in my Home component like so:
const stories = useSelector((state) => state.stories.userStories[userId])

When a user clicks a button in my component, I dispatch a method called updateStories which takes an array of story ids as well as a user id. It should update all story objects for a particular user id.
Here is the reducer:
   updateStoryViewedBy: (state, action) => {
    const { storyIds, storyCreatorId} = action.payload
    const stories = state.userStories[storyCreatorId]

    // loop over all story ids => find them in users stories => update them each individually
    storyIds.forEach((id) => {
        const s = stories?.find((s) => s?._id === id)
        s.isSeen = true
    })
},

Here I am directly mutating the state. If storyIds contains n id's, then the store is directly mutated n times, once for each object matching the story id. As each direct mutation to a store causes a re-render to a component that subscribes to that store, this would in theory update the Home component n times as it is using useSelector to subscribe to the store. However my Home component isn't re-rendering n times.
Why is this, and is using a loop in a reducer method to update individual objects in an array considered problematic in redux-tookit?
Could it be more beneficial to perhaps use state.userStories[userId] = state.userStories[userId].map(...) to only update the store once and avoid mutating? Thanks

"As each direct mutation to a store causes a re-render to a component that subscribes to that store" are you sure about that? I'd expect RDK to only rerender after your updateStoryViewedBy() finishes running


Here I am directly mutating the state. If storyIds contains n id's,
then the store is directly mutated n times, once for each object
matching the story id. As each direct mutation to a store causes a
re-render to a component that subscribes to that store, this would in
theory update the Home component n times as it is using useSelector to
subscribe to the store. However my Home component isn't re-rendering n
times.

I believe the assumption of each mutation causing a re-render does not happen here. The shallow equality checking may not be seeing each change because you are directly mutating the state, which you generally shouldn't be doing. I think this should be a better way of writing the reducer to create a new array instead of updating the current one. Not too sure about the logic here so let me know if you run into any issues with this
updateStoryViewedBy: (state, action) => {
  const { storyIds, storyCreatorId } = action.payload;
  const stories = state.userStories[storyCreatorId];

  if (stories) {
    const updatedStories = stories.map(story => {
      if (storyIds.includes(story._id)) {
        return { ...story, isSeen: true };
      }
      return story;
    });

    state.userStories[storyCreatorId] = updatedStories;
  }
}


Directly mutating state is OK in redux toolkit if OP is using createSlice or createReducer (which it appears that they're probably doing) due to it using immer. But I agree, I wouldn't expect each state mutation to cause a rerender.
